# How to create a circle with pie pieces

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would you accomplish creating this 
https://gyazo.com/c33bf9f65130af2cfa263eda04f85789

The different pie pieces needs to be elements because I want to be able to click them & display info about the months, hence why I cant create this as an image.

Appreciate all tips and examples.

Basicly I want to be able to create a circle(donut) with 12 pieces.

Comment: What about: http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: You can have image and map it, so different parts are clickable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: found this if you want a pure css approach http://www.custarddoughnuts.co.uk/article/2016/5/14/how-to-make-segmented-circles-in-css

Probably easier with SVG